# do i always need labeled data for ann?

Tags: deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

i put a small request on upwork where i am requesting help for a topic which is right now out of my skill zone.
The problem is a fitting problem of small rectangles in a big rectangle via a ANN.

Problem is the first freelancer baffled me a little bit with a comment.

So my thinking was, because the solution is easy verified and rewardable, that you can simply throw a ANN on this problem and with enough time it will perform better and better.
The freelancer requested labeled data first before he can tackle the problem(thats the comment which confuses me).
I was thinking that unlabeled random Input data is enough for the start.

Do I think wrong?

here the link to the job post.
[https://www.upwork.com/jobs/~01e040711c31ac0979](https://www.upwork.com/jobs/%7E01e040711c31ac0979)

edit: directly the original job description

I want python code for training a ANN and using it in a productive enviroment.
The problem it needs to solve is a rectangle fitting problem.

Input are
1000 small Rectangles(groupid,width,heigth,Oriantion(free,restricted,hor or ver), value) --sRect
1 big Rectangles(width, heigth)--bRect
Layout(bool,bool,bool,xpos,ypos,Oriantaion(hor or ver))--Layout

Output
Layout

The bRect will be duplicated to 3 Rectangles where the sRects need to be fitted into.
The Worth of the solution is determined by the sum of the value of sRect inside the bRect.
Further is the value decreased if the sRect is placed in the second bRect or third bRect.
sum(sRect(value))*0.98^nth bRect

Not all sRect needs to be placed.

Layout is structered that the three bool at the start represent at which bRect the sRect is placed. If a sRect is placed at one of the bRect, then the Solution Layout muss stay for this sRect the same.

Restricted Ori means all of the sRect with the same group need to be Oriantated the same way. Hor means the sRect is not turned, ver the sRect is turned by 90degrees.

Other then that normal rules apply, like all sRect needs to be inside the bRect and not Overlapp between sRect.

Looking forward to replys and i am avaible for further explanations.

edit: example picture

important i dont want to optimise for maximum plate usage, because it can happen that a smaller sRect can have a higher value then a bigger sRect.
[example fitting problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvQet.png)

Comment: It's impossible to access the link, so impossible to answer your question. In general to train a neural network you need a training set - which is a set of inputs and correct outputs. So in general the request looks reasonable.

Comment: thanks i changed it.

Comment: Even with the fixed link, it is customary on SO to provide all the details directly. If the site or your external post goes down, your question will become useless :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: implemented your comment @BartoszKP

Answer (score -1):

Without expected output for each input you cannot use the most standard training methodology - supervised learning. If you only have a way to **verify** the solution (e.g. in a game of chess you can tell me if I won but you cant tell me how to win) then the most standard approach is **reinforcement learning**. That being said, it is much more complex problem, not something that say a newcomer to the field of ML will be capable of doing (while supervised learning is something that one can do essentially by following basic tutorials online)

Comment: So it could be that the freelancer is simple only capable of providing a supervised learning model and not a reinforcement learning model? Okay gonna keep it in mind and search for a new one. But you are basiclly confirming my thoughts. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can't say what is their capability, but requesting labels definitely suggests they were looking to solve it through supervised learning.

Comment: Sorry @BartoszKP but this is plain wrong :) RL is literally a framework for any problem where for a specific x we cannot provide corresponding y, but instead for a prediction p(x) we can tell if it is good or not (aka we have a reward function, payoff, utility). It does not matter if it is classification or control. If you read problem desc of OP you would find that it is literally like this, OP only has a reward function (called "worth" in the description).

Comment: If i would solve/train it in a supervised learning process wouldnt that also mean that the programm is never able to outperform the training data?

Comment: @BartoszKP have you ever heard about Bandit problems? MDP of length 1 is still an MDP. You do not need an imposed time dimension to have an MDP, you can construct it yourself too (by splitting decision process to moving said boxes around). I recommend grabbing Sutton's book.

Comment: @Hirnfolter supervised learning is about replicating the mapping observed. If you want something that strictly outperforms it, we are again in RL land where the goal is to maximise the measurable quantity of interest (ie reward)

Comment: @lejlot You are right with MDPs of size 1. However it still doesn't make RL applicable here. Part of the formulation of the bandit problem from Sutton's book: "objective is to maximize the expected
total reward over some time period, for example, over 1000 action selections,
or time steps".  We already have a degenerate MDP, removing time makes it completely nonsensical. You end up with an algorithm for training a neural network - especially for this problem - because I don't expect you want to have an explicit map for every possible position of rectangles and track the average reward.

Comment: (calculating the average from a sample of size = 1 LOL ;) )

Comment: What you call "degenerate" and "nonsensical" is literally entire field of research (but please, feel free to tell entire RL AD industry what they do is nonsensical!). I will end this "discussion" here Bartosz, unfortunately, I can only leave you with reading materials on bandit problems, and *modeling* problems as MDPs. Good luck with your endevours.

Comment: @lejlot No need to be condescending :) I meant "degenerate" in a mathematical sense, sorry if I sounded offending. Nonsensical also wasn't meant as passive-aggressive - I hope you agree that calculating an average from a single element sample doesn't make much sense. So I really think Sutton's formulation is not relevant here, but by no means I don't claim such a formulation doesn't exist. Would be helpful if you provide a reference. Shouldn't be that hard if it's an entire field of research - I'm assuming you're quite familiar with.